# undefined method render_to_body for module AbstractController::Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a new rails app (3.2.3, ruby 1.9) and try to start server. Server started normally, but then i go to http://localhost:3000 i have error:

```
    => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Call with -d to detach
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    [2012-05-09 22:20:03] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2012-05-09 22:20:03] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [i686-linux]
    [2012-05-09 22:20:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3998 port=3000
    [2012-05-09 22:20:05] ERROR NameError: undefined method `render_to_body' for module `AbstractController::Rendering'
```

What is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced this issue when using HAML version 3.1.5.  Reverting to 3.1.4 fixed it.  A full stacktrace would be helpful to diagnose your issue if it is not HAML.

Comment: Was just going to answer the same. It looks like this has been fixed already, but not yet released: https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/adf6f21a95c4ff7fb4dff08556391b73c9eac18e

Answer (score 2):

If you just started your app better go with alpha

```
gem 'haml', '~> 3.2.0.alpha.10'
```

To be prepared to new stuff